# Script que contenga las respuestas de consulta SQL

Tags: javascript, sql, ajax, json

Gracias por prestar atencion a la pregunta. Para una pagina de resultados, cuyas respuestas deben estar en el propio index.html, y los valores dentro de un script.

Asi es cmo es ve el mismo antes de completar el formulario y hacer la consulta a la base de datos

```
  <script type="text/javascript">current_Form = 1;personsNum = ;asegID = '';age0 = ;refCode = '';$('.ref_code').html('');
 rep_ref_code = '';
 rep_ctl_code = '';
 province = '';asegID = '';countryId = '';fechaefecto = '';diaefecto = '';mesefecto = '';anyoefecto = '';parseResults({"pol":null,"ins_kids":null});togg902('');rep_s_code = '';otros_seguros = parseInt('');</script>
```

y asi luego, en el html del pagina

```
 <script type="text/javascript">current_Form = 1;personsNum = 3;asegID = '998';$('#sex0').attr('selectedIndex', 1); $('#btnRemove0').bind('click', {row: 0}, removeRow);$('#bday0').attr('selectedIndex', 05);$('#bmon0').attr('selectedIndex', 02);$('#byear0').val(1970);$('#sex1').attr('selectedIndex', 0); $('#btnRemove1').bind('click', {row: 1}, removeRow);$('#bday1').attr('selectedIndex', 23);$('#bmon1').attr('selectedIndex', 07);$('#byear1').val(1978);$('#sex2').attr('selectedIndex', 1); $('#btnRemove2').bind('click', {row: 2}, removeRow);$('#bday2').attr('selectedIndex', 04);$('#bmon2').attr('selectedIndex', 07);$('#byear2').val(2014);age0 = 47;age1 = 39;refCode = '71E36Z';$('.ref_code').html('71E36Z');
    rep_ref_code = '7188Z';  
    rep_ctl_code = '19200';
    province = 'San Francisco';asegID = '998';countryId = '1';fechaefecto = '20180101';diaefecto = '01';mesefecto = '01';anyoefecto = '2018';
 parseResults({"pol":[
  {"plan_nombre":"Basico","precio_total":"7106"},
  {"plan_nombre":"Super","precio_total":"6142"}, 
  {"plan_nombre":"Premium","precio_total":"9638"}
 ]});,"ins_kids":""});togg902('08');rep_s_code = '9loz47k857';otros_seguros = parseInt('0');mi_soft_id_emailing_contacts = 'qwr*****=';
 </script>
```

Y es desde aqui, de donde toma las variables para completarlas en el archivo funciones.php

por ejemplo

```
 tmpHTML = '<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 width10"><div class="copago";">' + copagoText + '</div>
```

Entonces, eso es lo que busco, modificar esas variables con mis resultados, y editar el html a mi gusto.

en el ejemplo anterior, la siguiente funcion crea un objeto , en otro archivo funciones.php

```
 function ajaxQuote(callback) 
 {
   if(callback == null) callback = function() {};

   var fechaactual=new Date();
   anyoactual=fechaactual.getFullYear();

   if (fechaefecto==9999){
    fechaefecto = "";
    }

  var quote = new Object();
  quote['rep_s_code'] = rep_s_code;
  quote['num_persons'] = personsNum;
  quote['id_insurer'] = asegID;
  quote['id_expert_help'] = expertHelpId;
  quote['id_country'] = countryId;
  quote['begin_date'] = fechaefecto;  
  quote['id_province'] = $('#provinceCode').val().substring(0,2);
  quote['postal_code'] = $('#provinceCode').val();
  quote['p1_bd'] = $('#byear0').val()+'-'+$('#bmon0').val()+'-'+$('#bday0').val();
  quote['p1_gender'] = $('#sex0').val();
  quote['p1_age'] = calculateAge($('#bmon0').val()+'/'+$('#bday0').val()+'/'+$('#byear0').val());
  quote['otros_seguros'] = otros_seguros;
  age0 = quote['p1_age'];
 for(i = 1; i < personsNum; i++)
{
 quote['p' + (i+1) + '_bd'] = $('#byear'+ i).val()+''+$('#bmon'+ i).val()+'-'+$('#bday'+ i).val();
 quote['p' + (i+1) + '_gender'] = $('#sex'+ i).val();
 quote['p' + (i+1) + '_age'] = calculateAge($('#bmon'+i).val()+'/'+$('#bday'+i).val()+'/'+$('#byear'+i).val());
      if (i == 1){
        age1 = quote['p' + (i+1) +'_age'];
     }
   }     
     $.ajax({      
      type : 'POST',
      url: root_folder + 'tq_quote_defs/add',
      data: quote,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data)
        {
          refCode = data.ref;
          $('.ref_code').html(data.ref);
          rep_ref_code = data.rep_ref_code;
          rep_ctl_code = data.rep_ctl_code;
          province = data.province;   
          if (fechaefecto!="") {
          f_efecto = diaefecto+'/'+mesefecto+'/'+anyoefecto;
        } 
        callback();
      }
    });
  }
```

y asi es como
como puedo hacer partiendo de que de mi consulta

```
 $consulta = "SELECT plan_nombre,precio_total FROM pol" ;
 $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
 $resultado -> execute();
 $data = $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 print json_encode($data);
```

Asi es como se ve ahora en el navegador. (en el mismo index.html)
Esto es lo que tengo ahora

```
[{"plan_nombre":"Basico","precio_total":"7106"},{"plan_nombre":"Super","precio_total":"6142"},{"plan_nombre":"Premium","precio_total":"9638"}]
```

Necesito que en vez de mostrarse en el `<div id="respuesta">[mi codigo]</div>`  quede en un script `<script>parseResults({"pol":[mi codigo]});</script>`

Asi esta ahora, y en el siguiente div id="respuesta" se muestra en el navegador

```
 <div id="respuesta">

  </div>
 <script>
    var form = document.querySelector('form');
    var boton = document.querySelector('[type=submit]');
    form.onsubmit = e => { //function(e){}
    boton.disabled = true;
    var fd = new FormData (form);
 
    e.preventDefault();

        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest( ); 
        ajax.open( 'POST', 'consulta.php' );
        ajax.upload.onprogress = e =>{
            var porcentaje = e.loaded * 100 / e.total ;
            document.querySelector( '#respuesta' ).innerHTML = porcentaje.toFixed(2)+'%';
             }
          ajax.onload = function( ){
            boton.disabled = false;
                document.querySelector( '#respuesta' ).innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
         form.reset();
         }      
            ajax.send(fd); 
         }
    </script>
```

Lo que necesito es completar las variables, pasarlas ahi,pero, principalmente me interesa el parseResults({"pol":null,"ins_kids":null});
Gracias

Comment: Hola, una función necesito. No

Comment: No lo entiendo, lo siento... ¿mi respuesta no cumple con lo que has pedido?  Tu decias esto: **Necesito que en vez de mostrarse en el `<div id="respuesta">[mi codigo]</div>` quede en un script `<script>parseResults({"pol":[mi codigo]});</script>`** y eso es lo que creo que se consigue con mi respuesta... ¿no era eso?

Comment: Hola , no frente a una compu para probar. Pero que pasa si pongo <script type="text/javascript" id="respuesta"><script> o mejor aún <script type="text/javascript">'parseResults({"pol":' + respuesta + '});' </script>   eso en el codigo fuente de la pagina de inicio una vez que se hace la consulta. que quede como muestro al inicio de la pregunta. Gracias

Comment: Ya me comentas cuando tengas tiempo y estes en la computadora. Empiezo a pensar que lo que pides es un eval() de la funcion con el codigo devuelto

Comment: Despues me interiorizo. Gracias

Comment: Hola, edite la pregunta, para que se entienda mejor. Se trata tanto de los resultados de la consulta , como todos las selecciones que se hicieron para llegar a la respuesta, lo que se registra registra.

Comment: Es la pagina, que se guardó  pará mostrarle al visitante la siguiente vez que la visite, y decirle "Hemos recuperado tu última consulta, 'la quieres ver otra vez' o 'Quieres hacer una nueva' ", en un modal.

Comment: Hola, actualice la pregunta, y amplie. Si me pueden dar una mano con esto, les estoy muy agradecido. Comence consultando por este <script>parseResults({"pol":null,"ins_kids":null});</script>  para no hacerlo tan largo. Tendria que poner en el primer null el json que trae la consulta.

Comment: Creo que en este caso estas teniendo un [problema XY](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_XY).  Seguramente no quieres lo que pides por ajax, pues dudo que te funcione aunque lo consigas, sino lo que pretendes es interpretar ese resultado con javascript cuando sea devuelto, y por eso te indiqué que quizás necesitas evaluar la respuesta con [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), o quizas con [json.parse()](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/js-json-parse-stringify-es), y asi conseguir lo que quieres.Si me equivoco corrigeme

Comment: Hola, edite la pregunta, y te muestro más del ejemplo.  No es con la intencion de corregirte, sólo te aporto algo más sobre lo que estoy intentando hacer y como. Muchas gracias por tus aportes

Answer (score 0):

No tengo claro si es esto lo que buscas:

En lugar de

```
print json_encode($data);
```

haces un

```
echo "<script>parseResults({\"pol\":".json_encode($data)."});</script>";
```

y que te lo muestre en el div `#respuesta` u otro elemento que quieras poner.

Comment: Hola, si , me quedo con esta respuesta.  Gracias

Comment: Si esta respuesta cumple con el objetivo de tu pregunta perfecto.  Y si es asi deberias marcarla como aceptada (creo que las preguntas que nunca son aceptadas son re-lanzadas de tanto en tanto de nuevo a la comunidad, y claro, si ya esta solucionado no hace falta eso).